# How to return a response before executing a method?

Tags: c#, return, return-value

I don't know if its possible, but I want to do this:
I want to return a response, but before executing a function, without waiting for a method response...

```
int Validate(saveobj obje)
{    
    // here I do my validations 
    return 0;
}

public string sendingObj(saveobj obje)
{
    //here I call my validation function 
    int result = Validate(obje);

    if(result != 0)
    // here I want to return ALLAYS something, because my web site cant wait all the process
    return result;
}

// here, no matter which response I give on my validate method I want to do this 

// Rest OF MY SENDING CODE !
```

Comment: You are going to have to be much more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning from a method is the **last** thing that happens in that function. All code after a `return` statement is unreachable.

But you can achieve what you want by making an asynchronous method call before you return. An asynchronous method call returns to your calling function immediately and does its work on another thread.

There are various ways to make asynchronous calls in .net, such as using a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or using the [`TaskFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782519.aspx), depending on the version of .net you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
int Validate(saveobj obje)
{    
    // here I do my validations 
    return 0;
}

public string sendingObj(saveobj obje)
{
       int result=0;
       Task.Run(()=>
       {
           result = Validate(obje);
           if(result != 0)
       });

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do like this ..

```
void sender(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // DO SOMETHING ! 


        }

        [HttpPost]
        public string Validate()
        {


            var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            backgroundWorker.DoWork += Foo;
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

            return "OK";





        }
```